# CF9 ORM EntityDelete with foreign key

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Using the usual example for one-to-many ORM objects "Artist" and "Art", I have an Art table with a column called ArtistID that is labeled as a foreign key of "Artist" (it uses, surprise, the primary key of the Artist table).  When I then have a specific Artist (called "thisArtist") and attempt to EntityDelete("thisArtist"), I get an error:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Art_Artists". The conflict occurred in database "ArtistTracker", table "dbo.Art", column 'ArtistID'.

I feel pretty confident that I am doing something dumb, either with my setup of relations or perhaps with my syntax.  Has anyone encountered this?  I don't see an example of how to EntityDelete() a specific Artist if it has foreign key constraints on entries in an Art table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Artist will likely have an "arts" property, correct? And that points to an Art CFC, presumably. Your arts property probably looks like property name="arts" cfc="Art" fieldtype="one-to-many";

What's missing is to tell ORM how to handle the case where you delete the Artist. In your case, you need to add a "cascade" attribute onto the arts property, like so: property... cascade="all-delete-orphan";

Then, when you entityDelete the Artist, Hibernate will also delete any orphaned Art elements that belonged to that artist.

When creating one-to-many relationships, you almost always want to specify cascade="one-to-many" and inverse="true".

Comment: I cover this, and a number of other things that cause pain to those new to ORM, in a recent presentation. Code is here: https://github.com/marcesher/ormzen

You can watch the preso here: http://cfmumbojumbo.com/cf/index.cfm/cfconferences/cfobjective-2011/orm-zen-marc-esher/